# Search for time in a JSON array and convert it to 'epochtime'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, time, epoch

How can i find the value of "time" in an JSON array like below:

```
{
   "data": [{
               "temperature": "20.0",
               "time": "2019-04-23 12:45:00+02:00"
           }]
}
```

And convert this value into a epochtime like below:

```
{
    "data": [{
                "temperature": "20.0",
                "timestamp": 1556016300000
            }]
}
```

Comment: in which language you want to do that ?

Comment: JSON, JavaScript

Comment: see the my answer

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan Thank you very much!! This is working fine for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Date.parse**

- Parse the object and then get the time
- Then parse date using Date.parse()
- Stringify the object again

```js
a = JSON.parse('{"data": [{"temperature": "20.0","time": "2019-04-23 12:45:00+02:00"}]}')
console.log(a)
a.data[0].time = Date.parse(a.data[0].time);
JSON.stringify(a);
console.log(a)
```